# View security review code scanner report

Tags: permissions, appexchange, security-review

I have published an app on AppExchange and I had to submit zap or burpscan report. However, today I am trying to review that report but I am getting insufficient privileges error. I am not able to download that report.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you log a case?

Comment: Not yet. I thought it is just a permission issue. I can log a case with salesforce if there is no solution on this.

Comment: FYI, this is not the code scanner, it's the web application scanner, called "Chimera".  The code scanner scans your source code with Checkmarx, and the results are not stored online in a portal, they are sent to you via email.